# Ошибка в Pyrogram. Как решить?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

```
vubor = input('Нажмите Enter! ')
if vubor == '':
    chat = input('Введите чат для парсинга: ')
    with Client('my_accont1', api_id, api_hash) as app:
        podpis = app.get_chat_members_count(chat)
        line = []
        for member in app.iter_chat_members(chat, limit=500):
            x = member.user.id
            line.append(x)
    for acc in account:
        with Client(f'{acc}', api_id, api_hash) as app:
            try:
                for user in line:
                    print(user)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    app.send_message(user, 'ky')
            except PeerFlood:
                time.sleep(2)
                print('Смена аккаунта')
```

pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PeerIdInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хотя бы написали, в чём заключается ошибка...

Comment: @4500zenja написал

Comment: Кто то ответит?